# Javascript document.write() - Replace PNG with GIF?

Tags: javascript

#### The Scenario

I have an asp.net web application with a HTML/CSS front end.
This all works fine but in Internet Explorer 6, the transparent PNG's that I use within the site are not transparent due to the poor design of this particular browser.

#### Solutions Attempted

I've already attempted various IE6 PNG Transparency fixes that didn't work.

#### The Proposed Solution

I thought about using GIF Image replacements for when the website detects that the browser is IE6. I don't have any javascript experience but someone has mentioned that I could use the "document.write()" feature off javascript to replace the PNG's with GIF's of the same image when using IE6 as the browser.

#### The Question

Please could someone explain to me how I would go about doing this?
Baring in mind I have an understanding of C# etc. but no javascript knowledge. I'm only just starting out as a web developer so simple explanations would aid me greatly.

Thanks for the help.
Regards.

Answer (score 5):

If we assume that

a) the gif files will have the same name and,

b) they already exist (you're not looking for some gif creator).

Then you just need to replace the src attribute for these files. This would be done `onload`, and doesn't require document.write(). Go with:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {

        var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

            var image_png_src = images[i].src;
            var image_gif_src = image_png_src.replace(".png", ".gif");
            images[i].src = image_gif_src;
        }
    };
</script>
-->
```

The nice thing about the above method is that it doesn't have to check if it's gif or png or jpg every time, because it simply won't replace it with .gif unless there is a .png. The bad thing is that if, for some reason, you have an image with .png in it (and I can't imagine why) but it isn't the file extension, it would replace that bit with .gif.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Won't this execute on any browser though?
Instead of checking if it's ie6 first?

Comment: Oh whoops. Let me fix that. The best way is to use conditional comments mentioned earlier. I'll add those.

Comment: I also made the condition `lte IE6`, which means any browser before IE7, so on the off chance it's IE5, it still works.

Comment: Typo in "getElementByTagName" (missing "s")

Comment: Awesome thankyou.
How would this work if i was getting multiple elements by tag name?

Comment: Do you mean multiple elements other than images? Because `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of all elements with the `img` tagname. The code had a type where I left out the "s" in Elements, which kangax very awesomely fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried jQuery's [pngFix](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/)? It makes the PNG transparent for IE 6 and you don't need to maintain two sets of images (PNG and GIF).

Using it doesn't require much javascript knowledge, so it wouldn't hurt to take a look at it.

Comment: Oh very nice. I think mine is a good old school way, but your answer certainly cuts through the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your img element has an id="my_img"

To detect if browser is IE6, use conditional comments. Further, add Javascript like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("my_img").src = "images/alternate.gif"
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

You might also like to have a look at this:
[IE6 PNG transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency)

Comment: @judi, the `<!--[if IE 6]>` is a unique feature of IE called conditional-commenting. It means that if the browser in brackets is whatever you put there, the comments go away and it's executed by the browser. If it is NOT that browser, it stays commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code runs a replace on IE6 only:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE 6/) != null)) {
    var images = document.getElementByTagName("img");
       for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
          var src = images[i];
          if(src.match(/\.png$/)){ //endswith .png
             images[i].src = src.replace(/\.png$/g,'.gif');
          }
       }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery version of the replacement:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // List all PNG images
    $("img[src$=.png]").each(function(i, img)
    {
        // Replace with GIF versions
        img.src = img.src.replace(/\.png$/, '.gif')
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

W3Schools is a great place to start if you're wanting to learn javascript.
For example, take a look at the [getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp) function...

There is also a browser detect function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp)

Good luck - hope that helps.