# Looking for IE6 .PNG Transparency Fix for both img tag and background images

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Not sure if this exists as I have been googling all around and can't find anything great. Thought I would post this question prior to redesigning the page I am working on.

Is there anyway to fix the transparency problems with .png's in IE6 for both image tags and background images?

Please tell me there is a magical javascript that just does it!!! I am assuming that I will have to apply two different fixes to address img tags and then background images. If this is the case, what have you found is best?

Comment: Please check this quesiton - IE6 PNG transparency - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may fix the problem

Go to
http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Download the file iepngfix.zip

To download permanently: iepngfix.zip (40kb). Open "iepngfix.html" in a browser; step by step instructions are within.

After downloading in css

```
img, div { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

[jquery.pngFix.js - PNG-Transparency for Windows IE 5.5 & 6 (IE PNG Fix)](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/)