# making png transparent in ie6 with wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE6 PNG transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency)

i'm running a wordpress site and when viewing the site in IE6 i would like it to show my png transparent instead of with a grey background, anyone who can help? found solutions but the make me confused since wordpress has different tags to work with

Comment: People need to stop caring about IE6.  IT IS DEAD!

Comment: IE6 is not dead, not by a long shot, not until governments and corporations get off it...

Comment: @Rocket , Lloyd is right, companies still use IE6 so you should still support IE6 if nessecary ;)

Comment: Sadly, Lloyd is correct.  I maintain a site that is predominantly design oriented, you'd think everyone would be on the latest Macs, but alas, 16% of our traffic is still from IE6! ::cry::

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency

Comment: @mkoistinen Probably just certain government departments keeping an eye on your site :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use alpha-transparency and do not need more than 256 colors - you can try to save your image as 8-bit-png file with additional alpha-channel.

Here's a good explanation:
http://www.ethanandjamie.com/blog/37-user-interface/81-png8-transparency-without-fireworks

The funny thing is that IE6 will ignore the alpah-channel. Other (newer) browsers like Firefox, Opera, IE7+, Chrome, and Safari will try to display the image using the alpha-channel.

I prefer to use this solution because it does not require CSS hacks or Javascript.