# Logo image browser issue with background color

Tags: html, css

am facing some unusual problem with my logo.
http://handigital.com/
in this site, in some browsers i get the white background color for the logo.
the logo image is a PNG-24 format and it is transparent.
i have no clue why it is showing white background?
You can tell me what might be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Which browser you are facing issue?

Comment: Some browsers such as...? IE6 doesn't support transparent PNGs without some hacks.

Comment: If you mean IE6 and transparent PNGs, read the answers of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency).

Comment: looks good in IE8, chrome, safari and firefox

Comment: You should flip the image so the bottom line goes upwards, denotes positivity and growth, as opposed to the line ripping downwards like that, usually meaning declining, negativity, loss, debt etc. Just a thought. Not sure about your problem.

Comment: I am currently using FF8 and it works just fine. Transparancy issues only occur in IE6 or older, but there are known hacks for that.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 has known transparency bugs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Web_browser_support_for_PNG

Comment: Am facing problem in firefox 8.0 in windows platform, same url in fedora doesn't throw error. it is working fine in IE.but in apple compuer and in iPad also same issue.

Comment: Am facing problem in firefox 8.0 in windows platform, same url in fedora doesn't throw error. it is working fine in IE.but in apple compuer and in iPad also same issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you use png-8 format  ...it works fine in ie6 +

Answer (score 0):

The best way i found, I use Macromedia Fireworks, or any image editing program that allows you full ability to customize the palettes etc.

Export the PNG as such

- Either 8-Bit PNG, Transparent, Adaptive (acts like a GIF in IE6) or
- 32-Bit PNG (only modern browsers)

**Note**: 8-Bit will be slightly visibly degraded depending on how many colors are in the palette