# Modernizr.load not providing input and textarea placeholder support  in IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, placeholder, modernizr

I'm using Mathias Bynens's rather good [jQuery placeholder plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to display placeholders in [my site](http://donaldjenkins.com/) in browsers that don't support it natively.  I'm calling the plugin using a [custom version](http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/wp-content/themes/belgravia/js/modernizr_custom_20089.js) of Modernizr in the footer of the page, immediately after the Google Analytics code.  I'm combining it with a script (described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency)) to display PNGs in IE6.

Modernizr is called in the header, and the site also uses Typekit.  jQuery is only called when the placeholder functionality is missing as it isn't actually needed otherwise.

The relevant code—which I'm calling in the footer of a WordPress blog—looks like this:

#### 1. Fix PNGs:

```
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s)
    }(document, 'script'));
    function fixPngs() {
        for (i = 0; i  0) {
                fixPng(a, document.images[i])
            }
        }
    }
    function fixPng(a, b) {
        b.src = "http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/media/themes/belgravia/2/spacer.gif";
        b.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"
        a "', sizingMethod='scale')"
    };
```

#### 2. Add placeholders:

```
    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.input.placeholder,
        nope: ["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", "http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/wp-content/themes/belgravia/js/placeholder.js"],
        complete: function () {
            $('input, textarea').placeholder();
        }
    });
```

#### 3. Call PNG script

```
fixPngs();
```

Unfortunately, the placeholder displays in IE6 and IE9, but *not* in IE7 or IE8. I've tried setting up a html [sandbox site](http://dbdj.org) that replicates the resources described above, to try and pinpoint what was causing the issue—but I'm getting the same problem.  I've tried other placeholder plugins, with the same result.

---

**EDIT**:
After Mathias Bynens's helpful response, and after testing whether placeholder jQuery plugins worked *without* Modernizr, I've concluded it's a Modernizr issue: if the placeholder plugin and jQuery are loaded systematically, without using Modernizr, the placeholders display in all browsers—when loaded via Modernizr, they display in IE6 and 9, but not IE 7 and 8.

I've tried switching from a custom version of Modernizr to a development version, but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/wp-content/themes/belgravia/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js is a 404 error for me. I’m guessing that’s the problem? :)

```
$ curl -sI http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/wp-content/themes/belgravia/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js | head -n 1
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

This might be unrelated to your issue, but you shouldn’t simply use the `Modernizr.input.placeholder` check if you need `textarea@placeholder` support. The reason for this is that some browsers support `input@placeholder`, but not `textarea@placeholder`. `Modernizr.input.placeholder` only represents `input` support.

The plugin performs this check internally anyway, but if you want to use Modernizr, do it like this:

```
Modernizr.load({
  'test': Modernizr.input.placeholder && Modernizr.textarea.placeholder,
  'nope': ["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", "http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/wp-content/themes/belgravia/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"],
  'complete': function() {
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
  }
});
```

That said, if you don’t need `textarea@placeholder` support, you could remove the check, and remove `textarea` from the selector.

Comment: Wow, that was quick—thanks.  Not sure why you're getting a 404 on the script—loading normally for me…  I actually need `input` support on most pages, and `textarea` support on the contact page (which is outside of WordPress and has actually displays placeholders in `textarea` boxes in IE 6 and IE9…)

Comment: Can't work out why you're both getting a 404 on the script.  Weird.

Anyway, the reason I'm using Modernizr is so as not to load jQuery + Mathias's plugin unless needed—which they are only if the functionality is missing.

I've corrected the code to include Mathias's suggestion, but still getting no luck in IE7 and 8.

Comment: After checking with my CDN, it seems they _do_have an issue with `js`files with full stops in them… I've renamed the file to http://cdn.donaldjenkins.com/wp-content/themes/belgravia/js/placeholder.js — but still getting the same result: placeholders in IE6 and 9, but not in IE7 and 8…  Not sure where to look next.

Comment: @DonaldJenkins I do see the placeholders in IE7 on http://dbdj.org/. Everything seems to work fine here.

Comment: I've actually narrowed it down to Modernizr.  If you load jQuery and  the plugin systematically without carrying out the Modernizr test, the placeholders display in all versions of IE.  If you use `Modernizr.load`, they only show up in IE6 and IE9.  The same happens with other placeholder plugins, making it likely it's something with Modernizr.

Comment: Basically concluded it's a Modernizr issue: if the placeholder plugin and jQuery are loaded systematically, without using Modernizr, the placeholders display in all browsers—when loaded via Modernizr, they display in IE6 and 9, but not IE 7 and 8.

Comment: The 'complete' function seems to be executed independent of the test result. So in case of a negative result `$('input, textarea').placeholder();` will call an undefined function – or am I missing something?